# Python split() list index out of range with tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

I am using Tweepy to pull tweets from twitter and reply to them automatically, and I want to split at the beginning of the users tweet so the bot isn't constantly @'ing itself and replying in an infinite loop.

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 47, in <module>
    text = text.split("@DungeonTrekker ", 1)[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is the code:

```
text = x.text
text = text.split("@DungeonTrekker ", 1)[1] # Split tweet

API.update_status("@" + x.user.screen_name + text +  x.user.name, x.id) # Tweet
print("Status Updated") # Console output

exclude.append(x.id) # Add to excluded list
```

When I run the code with a given string as an input then it is fine. I have also printed out the actual string `text` and it is correctly taking in the string, so the issue is with the split() function, any ideas guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text = text.split("@DungeonTrekker ", 1)[1] # Split tweet`
This line is telling text to split  at the instance of `@DungeonTrekker`

If @DungeonTrekker is at the beginning of the line, you'll have nothing before it, and the rest of the text after it.  Index 0 would be '' and index 1 would be the rest of the tweet.

However, if you are taking another user's tweet, chances are there will not be `@DungeonTrekker`  at the beginning, so unless it is mentioned in the text of the tweet, you'll only have index 0.

You could split at the   (space) and take the first index to solve this, that way whatever the user name is (I don't use twitter but I assume that a space is not allowed in the user name), it will split it properly.

Comment: Jonathan my friend, you are a legend

Answer (score 0):

a = "ababdababd adbabd "

a.split("1 ", 1)[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
IndexError: list index out of range

i think your problem is in your string it just won't split